# System.AggregateException: 'One or more hosted services failed to stop. (The operation was canceled.)'

Tags: c#, xunit

I am writing integration test using XUnit and my web api code is also in C# NET 6 and EF Core.

When I debug it, it can reach the web api and its service layer. But when it reaches EF Core context query example `private Message? GetMessage() => _myContext.Messages.OrderBy(m => m.CreatedUtc).FirstOrDefault();`, it breaks at `Program.cs`.

[image]

This is the code for `TestingWebAppFactory` class

```
public class TestingWebAppFactory<TEntryPoint> : WebApplicationFactory<Program> where TEntryPoint : Program
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                d => d.ServiceType ==
                    typeof(DbContextOptions<MyContext>));

            if (descriptor != null)
                services.Remove(descriptor);

            services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase("myinmemorydb");
            });

            var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
            using (var appContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyContext>())
            {
                try
                {
                    appContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Log errors or do anything you think it's needed
                    throw;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and this is my code in Xunit

```
public class MyServiceTest : IClassFixture<TestingWebAppFactory<Program>>
{

    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public MyServiceTest(TestingWebAppFactory<Program> factory)
    {
        _client = factory.CreateClient();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task WhenAValidMessagePosted_ThenShouldReturn()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = source.Token;
        source.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("https://localhost:xxxx/api/service/message/post?cronExpresson=0");
    }
}
```

Comment: Any inner exception? Can you manually create a `DbContext` and access your in-memory database? Can you try to not dispose your `appContext` in `TestingWebAppFactory` ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#customize-webapplicationfactory))

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem might be related to how you configure your EF Core context within the testing environment.

Try ensuring that your test project references the necessary NuGet packages for EF Core and EF Core In-Memory Database.

Verify that your `MyContext` class inherits from `DbContext` and is correctly configured.

Update the `TestingWebAppFactory` class to use the correct generic type parameter (`TEntryPoint`) for the `WebApplicationFactory`. Try replacing `Program` with `TEntryPoint` like this:

```
public class TestingWebAppFactory<TEntryPoint> : WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> where TEntryPoint : class
{
    // ...
}
```

Check that your `MyContext` class is registered correctly in the testing environment. In your `TestingWebAppFactory` class, replace `Program` with `TEntryPoint` when registering the `DbContextOptions<MyContext>`. Try updating your `ConfigureWebHost` method like this:

```
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
            d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<MyContext>));

        if (descriptor != null)
            services.Remove(descriptor);

        services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseInMemoryDatabase("myinmemorydb");
        });
        
        // ...
    });
}
```

Ensure that the `MyContext` instance is properly resolved in your test class. In your `MyServiceTest` class, update the `TestingWebAppFactory` generic type parameter to `TEntryPoint` like this:

```
public class MyServiceTest : IClassFixture<TestingWebAppFactory<Program>>
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public MyServiceTest(TestingWebAppFactory<Program> factory)
    {
        _client = factory.CreateClient();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar error, and I implemented the interface `IAsyncLifetime`:

```
public class MyServiceTest : IClassFixture<TestingWebAppFactory<Program>>, IAsyncLifetime
{
    private readonly TestingWebAppFactory<Program> _factory;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public MyServiceTest(TestingWebAppFactory<Program> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        _client = factory.CreateClient();
    }

    public Task InitializeAsync()
    {
       using (_waf.CreateDefaultClient()) { }

       return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task DisposeAsync()
    {
       await using var scope = _waf.Services.CreateAsyncScope();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task WhenAValidMessagePosted_ThenShouldReturn()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = source.Token;
        source.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("https://localhost:xxxx/api/service/message/post?cronExpresson=0");
    }
}
```

Based on [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/49615).